# Empty institute produces non empty short institute

Tags: beamer

In my beamer presentation, I have intentionally left the `\institute` macro undefined/blank and when I test whether the automatically set macro `\insertinstitute` is empty, it does indeed produce the expected result, i.e. it is empty.
However, in the same document, the other macro (the short version) `\insertshortinstitute` appears to be set even though it shouldn't.
Is this a bug? Or more general, how can I fix it to actually be empty?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,compress,
%              draft,
               xcolor={dvipsnames,table},
               aspectratio=1610,
              ]{beamer}
\title[title]{The Title}
\subtitle[subtitle]{The Subtitle}
\author[author]{The Author}
% Not set:
%\institute[institute]{The Institute}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{title page}{my title page}
{
  \usebeamerfont{normal text}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}%
        [wd=1\paperwidth,sep=0.04\paperwidth,
          leftskip=0.01\paperwidth,rightskip=0.01\paperwidth]%
        {title}%
    {\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\strut\par}%
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
    \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\strut\par}%
    \fi
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vspace{0.2\paperheight}
  \parbox[b][0.25\paperheight]{0.5\textwidth}{%
    {\usebeamerfont{author}\usebeamercolor[fg]{author}\insertauthor\strut\par}
    \ifx\insertinstitute\@empty%
      {no institute\strut\par}%
    \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{institute}\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}Institute: \insertinstitute\strut\par}
    \fi
    \ifx\insertshortinstitute\@empty%
      {no short institute\strut\par}%
    \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{institute}\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}Short Institute: \insertshortinstitute\strut\par}
    \fi%
    \vfill
    \ifx\insertdate\@empty%
      {\usebeamerfont{date}\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}\today\strut\par}
    \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{date}\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}\insertdate\strut\par}
    \fi
  }\hfill%
}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[my title page]

\begin{document}

\frame[plain]{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

And here is the resulting output:

[image: output of MWE]

I just noticed, that a quick and dirty fix would be to manually redefine it (at the end of the preamble), like:

```
\renewcommand*{\insertshortinstitute}{}
```

I am still interested whether this is a bug, or expected behaviour, or I am making a mistake somewhere along the way.

Comment: The macro `\insertshortinstitute` doesn't simply contain the short version, since it can also take an optional argument. You might try with `\ifx\beamer@shortinstitute\@empty...` but I can't test right now so it's a guess.

Comment: @campa Thanks for the input, I have tried it, and the result does not change. It might not even be defined, when I try printing it, I get an undefined control sequence error.

Comment: Strange, I've tested it and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into `beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty` for inspiration and use

```
\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
```